# Session auto expiry if user in idle

Tags: php

I need to destroy the session if the user is idle up to 10 minutes also how to find the time of last activity of the user ,

```
if ($_SESSION['last_activity'] > 600)
{
 session_unset();   
 session_destroy();
}
```

is this correct way..

Comment: You don't need to call `session_destroy()`. If you call `session_destroy()` then you need to call `session_start()` again. Also, beware that if you keep **anything** else in session, that will be lost as well with `session_unset()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes?lq=1

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049890/php-destroy-session-if-not-any-action-in-10-minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `session.gc_maxlifetime`

```
Set session.gc_maxlifetime = 600 in phi.ini
```

or

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',600); // in your script
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//on pageload
session_start();

$idletime=60;//after 60 seconds the user gets logged out

if (time()-$_SESSION['timestamp']>$idletime){
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
}else{
    $_SESSION['timestamp']=time();
}

//on session creation
$_SESSION['timestamp']=time();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for activity before resetting the time:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['last_activity']) && $_SESSION['last_activity'] > 600){
    session_unset();   
    session_destroy();
}else{
    $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
}
```